# How to speed update time of IDR Register STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I have a question about the IDR Register of STM32
I set the pin0 of the ODR Register to 1 in my code below and I want to check, if the pin0 in the IDR register is set to 1. The problem is, after setting the pin to 1, I must wait 1 second until the pin in the IDR register is set to 1.

**How can I read the pin state without waiting?**

How can I solve this problem?

```
void init_pins(void)
{
    GPIOG->OTYPER |= (0x01 << 0); // Pin 0 as open drain
    GPIOG->OTYPER &= ~(0x01 << 1); // Pin 1 as push - pull

    GPIOG->BSRRL  =  0x01 << 1; // Pin 1 to High
    GPIOG->BSRRL  =  0x01 << 0; // Pin 0 to High

    microsecond_Delay(1000000);

    if( !(GPIOG->IDR & 0x01) )
    {
        errorCode = -1 ; //Error Code for Bus not floating
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you init PORTG? Why don't you use HAL?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Use CMSIS** header files provided by the STM.
2. If configure pin as open drain you can't set it HIGH. It has to be done by the external pull-up. Your configuration is just wrong. If you do not have external pull-up (or at leat the internal one) the state of the pin if you do not set it to zero is unpredictable.